# Sockets not working after certain calls

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I am making an application which requires intercommunication between client and servers running on different ports on same machine. I wish to send multiple(quite a lot) messages across the network(just from client -> server not in reverse direction). So every time I need to send message I call the following function. For some Initial calls it works fine then mysteriously it starts retuning error : setsockopt bad file descriptor. From internet I found that close does not destroy the socket completely and just removes its interface thereby rendering it useless for future. Maybe the number of sockets that can be used has some limit and that has been reached and new sockets are not created because of that. How can I avoid that problem. Or is there possibly anyway by which I can create a socket once and use it repeatedly.   I am using unix C environment. Thanks in advance.

```
void client(char ip[50], int port, char s[50])
{
   while(clientActive==1){
   }
   clientActive=1; 
  memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));


  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");

    }

  if (setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(const void *)&true1,sizeof(true1)) == -1)
   {
    perror("Setsockopt");   
   }

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
    }
    else                                               
    {
      strcpy(sendBuff, s);
      send(sockfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff),0);
    }

    usleep(1000);
    clientActive=0;
 close(sockfd);
}
```

Updated code

```
void client(char ip[50], int port, char s[50])
{
   while(clientActive==1){

   }
   clientActive=1;


  memset(recvBuff, '0' ,sizeof(recvBuff));
so_linger.l_onoff = 1;
so_linger.l_linger = 0;

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))< 0)
      {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
      }
    else
    {
    if (setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_LINGER,&so_linger,sizeof so_linger)==-1);
     {
      perror("Setsockopt");
     }   
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
      printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
    }
    else                                               
    {
      strcpy(sendBuff, s);
      send(sockfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff),0);
    }
    usleep(1000);
    clientActive=0;
 close(sockfd);
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `clientActive` for some kind of synchronization.  This won't work reliably.  You could easily be having thread contention for the port. As others have said your code has error handling problems, and closing the socket between sends is a bad idea.  Do you close a file every time you write a line?

Comment: It's not necessary to copy s to sendBuff. Just send s directly; this will increase performance. -And yes, if you need the clientActive, you should use Atomic operations for test+set. Clearing does not require an atomic operation.

Comment: @Gene I have edited the question for updated code.

Comment: This code is just a mess. You're continuing after errors as though they hadn't happened, and you're not printing out the actual errors when you get them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the socket open, why are you closing it at the end of this function?  Why don't you open it at the beginning of your program and close it at the end?

Comment: I have tried it. then it does not connect to the destination and throws an error.